# Check bootloader existence in a block device

Tags: linux, grub

How can I check if a bootloader (i.e. grub2) is installed on a block device (e.g. CF card)?
I know I can mount the device and peek some files but how can I be sure the bootloader is installed without having to test it (try to boot it on some device)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved quite easily by using the dd(1) command and copying the first 512 bytes from a given medium. Like:

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=mbr-sdX bs=512 count=1
```

Then check if that file contains the hex signature ``0xAA55'' (don't forget to account for endianess of the machine). See [1] for more details.

[1]http://mirror.href.com/thestarman/asm/mbr/GRUB.htm

Comment: Awesome! Thanks pfo.
So, running:

'$ hexdump mbr-sdX | grep aa55'

Should give me something like this right?

'00001f0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 aa55'

Thanks in advance.
Humber

Comment: Exactly, I just verfied this on my Mac. As already said you should take care of the endianness of the machine, ie on an intel box you should grep for ``55 aa''.

Comment: Oops, sorry.
If after testing a little bit I realize that '$hexdump -Cv mbr-sdX' show some grub string when the bootloader is installed and almost all 0 when it isn't.

Comment: Yeah, but the method i described can be used for other MBRs too. It seams that some versions of GRUB also include a ``GRUB'' string in the MBR.

Comment: Great. Actually, my grub version (Grub 2 1.97~beta4-1ubuntu4.1) does show the GRUB string.
Tnks again Pfo